# Printing an Excel spreadsheet created by someone else even if saved with a different filename

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Why can I not print an Excel spreadsheet (in Excel 2013) created by someone else even if I have saved it with a different filename?

Comment: Probably many possibilities.  Any insight into your problem besides you have a problem at all?  Software errors? Things tried?  Printer Errors?  Or nothing; print and all seems fine but no output?

Comment: No other printing problems, but it seems that if the originator had secure print set up, they can print the amended spreadsheet using their password

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have ever seen this is when someone used a piece of VBA to block printing of a workbook.

Take a look at [This link](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1802-excel-prevent-printing-sheet.html) and take a look to see if you can find any similar code in the VBA for your workbook.

1. Hold down the ALT + F11 keys to open the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.
2. And then in the left Project Explorer, double click ThisWorkbook to open the module
3. Look for code similar to the following:

> ```
> Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
>
> Cancel = True
>
> End Sub
> ```

4. Check all other items too (each worksheet etc)

If there is, you should be able to comment it out (place a single quote ' at the beginning of every line) and then print away.

This may not be it - given that you arent having printing problems with anything else,  it stumped me once, so may help someone sometime.

Alternatively, are you seeing any errors? what are the symptoms you are seeing other than it nor printing?